# randomly select M records from a file of N records

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

Need to randomly select M records (means each record in the file have the same probability to choose) from a file with N records (N > M). Wondering if any solution which read file only once?

The only method I think about is select each record with probability M/N, but this way could result in either less than M or more than M records.

Any smarter ideas are appreciated.

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably need is the reservoir sampling algorithm ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)).

Not only it grantees that you get exactly M records with equal probability but you only need to read the input only once and you don't need to know N beforehand.

Complexity is O(N).

Comment: Thanks Sorin, looks smart, vote up before read in more details. :)

Comment: Hi Sorin, studied the algorithm and confused by this conclusion in the wikipedia page you referred -- "for all i, the ith element of S is chosen to be included in the reservoir with probability k/i.", my confusion is, since for the first k elements, it is pre-filled into reservoir, whether the first k elements of S has equal probability to be included comparing to remaining elements in S? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they have equal probability. That is because they can be replaced by later elements. Say you have a reservoir of `k=1`. So the probability of the first element to remain in the reservoir (since you add it by default) is `product(i=2->N; 1 - 1/i)` which is 1/N (what you want). You should get k/N for the more general case. You can do the same computation for later elements and it should all result in k/N. This holds true throughout the runs. So if you stop in the middle the reservoir will hold a equal probability sample of the elements you've seen so far.

Comment: Thanks Sorin, vote up. Another confusion from the wikipedia page is, "After the (i-1)th round, let us assume, the probability of a number being in the reservoir array is k/(i-1)", the question is, how do we know if the assumption of `k/(i-1)` is correct for `i-1`? Since I think the assumption needs to work for `i-1` in order to utilize it in induction for the case of `i`.

Comment: You put the first k in the reservoir directly. So, when `i=k` the probability of a number being selected if `k/k = 1` which is true since you just put them there. So using induction you prove it's true for `i=k+1` then using that for `i=k+2` and so on for any number you want `>k`.

Comment: Thanks Sorin, mark your reply as answer, thanks for the patience to explain to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Select `M` *unique* random numbers, put them in an array, sort them, and then read the file in once.  As you read in the `i`th record of the file, keep it if `i` is in the array, otherwise discard it.  This takes `O(M)` memory and is running time `O(N + M log M)`.

Comment: Super smart, awesome TheGreatContini!

Comment: Vote up and will mark your reply as answer when time permits. As you answered so fast. Cool. :)

Comment: BTW, TheGreatContini, does it matter if I do not know the size of the file? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa You need to know the size of the file because you need your random numbers selected from `1` to `N` (or `0` to `N-1`).  If you do not know in advance, then you need to read the file twice: one time to compute the size, a second time to perform this algorithm.

Comment: Thanks TheGreatContini, mark your reply as answer. Have a good night.

Comment: Whereas this works, it's not a particularly good solution because it requires you to know the size of the file, takes O(M) extra space, and requires O(M log M) time for sorting. Reservoir sampling is faster, doesn't require any extra space, and doesn't require that you know the size of the time.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the advice, vote up and have a nice day. :)